# curl not bring installed to /usr/local/bin with homebrew

Tags: command-line, homebrew, zsh

I'm trying to install the latest version of curl with homebrew, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I installed it with the following command and it seems to happen successfully:

```
$ brew install curl
```

To add `/usr/local/bin` to my PATH, I ran the following command:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

However, curl still was on the old version, and running `which curl` would point to `/usr/bin/curl`. I tried to see if there was anything in `/usr/local/bin`, but was surprised by the output:

```
$ which /usr/local/bin/curl
/usr/local/bin/curl not found
```

Sure enough, there was no symlink in `/usr/local/bin`. What am I doing wrong? I am on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message Homebrew shows you after installing `curl` gives you all the required details

```
==> Caveats
curl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have curl first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/pse/.bash_profile

For compilers to find curl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"

For pkg-config to find curl you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

So you need to either alias the Homebrew curl so it gets picked up in interactive shells or add its path to PATH as explained in the text above (which explains it for `bash`, you need to add the respective entry to `.zshrc` (or wherever `zsh` takes its paths from)).

Comment: Do you mean I need to put those `export` commands into my `.zshrc` file as well? I'm not trying to use curl with a compiler or pkg-config, I'm just trying to use it in the terminal

Comment: @SkeletonBow You need to adjust PATH accordingly (or define an alias for `curl`).

Comment: Isn't that what I did with the second command in my question? Or am I missing something here... when I run `echo $PATH` I get `/Users/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin...`

Comment: @SkeletonBow Did you source your .zshrc afterwards, or open a new Terminal window? Are you using zsh?

Comment: Yes to both of them. I even checked in my `.zshrc` file that the first line is `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. It also seems like `/usr/local/bin` is in my PATH as evidences by running the `echo $PATH` command. But it looks like homebrew just doesn't create a symlink for curl in `/usr/local/bin`...

Comment: @skeletonbow please reread the answer, it‘s not about /usr/local/bin. Homebrew intentionally doesn‘t link curl there, the reason for this is also in the answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I guess the echo command didn't write to `.zshrc` for whatever reason.